# Filter array object children javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to filter an array with children

I'm using the .filter function and is not filtering the children the way I need

This is the object example

```
var arr =  {
       "items":[
          {
             "name":"Stackoverflow",
             "type":"development",
             "children":[
                {
                   "title":"web",
                   "titleName":"web site"
                },
                {
                   "title":"web",
                   "titleName":"site"
                }
             ]
          },
          {
             "name":"Jon Snow",
             "type":"actor",
             "children":[
                {
                   "title":"foo 2",
                   "titleName":"foo 3"
                },
                {
                   "title":"no foo",
                   "titleName":"bar 2"
                }
             ]
          }
       ]
    }
```

Code example:

```
var searchWord = 'foo'

arr.items.filter(item => {
    return (item.children.some(c => c.titleName.indexOf(searchWord) > -1))
})
```

this will return the items that have the filter correctly but I need that filters the children in the return

```
//The returned children
{ 
 "name":"Jon Snow",
 "type":"actor",
 "children":[{title: "foo 2", titleName: "foo 3"}, {title: "no foo", titleName: "bar 2"}]
}
//The expected should be 
{ 
 "name":"Jon Snow",
 "type":"actor",
 "children":[{title: "foo 2", titleName: "foo 3"}]
}
```

Comment: I tried for a long time but not find a good solution. Almost seems like a bug. One solution that might not suit your needs is to filter one more time just on the children. This however requires uniq titleNames which might not be the case. 
`arr.items[0].children = arr.items[0].children.filter(c => c.titleName.indexOf(searchWord) > -1);`

Comment: The solution from @christian-fritz worked for me, however this will change the value for the original array, if you need the original object you need to "clone" it, I did it with JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(OBJECT)) and worked with the cloned object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not actually filtering the children, you are filtering only the top-level items.

This should work correctly:

```js
var searchWord = 'foo'
res = arr.items.filter(item => {
  item.children = item.children.filter(c => c.titleName.indexOf(searchWord) > -1);
  return (item.children.length > 0);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
arr.items.filter(item => {
   if (item.children.some(c => c.titleName.indexOf(searchWord) > -1)){
        console.log(item);
      item.children=item.children.find(x=>x.titleName.indexOf(searchWord) > -1);
      return item
   }
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ahwctv8q/